# Installed Python Package with pip, but cannot import for use

Tags: python, path, pip, installation

Apologies if this is the noobest question in existence, but I *think* this is an issue with my path? Terminal output below

```
Vincents-MacBook-Pro:~ vincentlevinger$ pip install binance
Requirement already satisfied: binance in /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/site-packages
Vincents-MacBook-Pro:~ vincentlevinger$ python import binance
/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/Resources/Python.app/Contents/MacOS/Python: can't open file 'import': [Errno 2] No such file or directory
Vincents-MacBook-Pro:~ vincentlevinger$
```

Comment: That's not how you import stuff in Python... first launch ``python``, then try ``import binance``.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is not Python:

```
python import binance
```

Here, you are trying to invoke the Python interpreter with the `python` command. But this command does not take Python code as argument, it takes an executable! So you are actually trying to run the `import` script, which of course, doesn't exist.

If you want to access the Python interpreter without feeding him a script, just run the `python` command without arguments:

```
python
```

It will open the Python interpreter (you can recognise it by its prompt: `>>>`). Now you can type Python code:

```
>>> import binance
```

Comment: I am however still getting a snag on this. After running python and then importing binance, it get's hung up on the 'import requests' call that happens on line 4... I get 'ImportError: No module named requests'. Link [here] (https://github.com/toshima/binance/blob/master/binance.py)

Comment: You're missing the `requests` module. `pip install requests` should do the trick.

Comment: Heyo that did it! I guess when in doubt, install it out ;). Thanks again for your help!

Answer (score 0):

To run a Python code from the command line use this syntax:

```
python -c "import binance"
```

Option `-c` accept a string (one string, hence the quotes that combine space-separated words into one parameter) that will be interpreted by python. You can even pass a multiline script:

```
python -c "
import binance
print(binance.prices())
"
```